# How do I listen for click events for an ActionBar nav button when a SearchView is visible?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I'm trying to catch click events for the nav button in my `ActionBar`. This method catches *most* clicks:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // Nav button pressed. Do stuff here.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

However it isn't called when my `SearchView` is visible. In this state, tapping the button closes the `SearchView`. Tapping it *again* triggers the callback above.

This isn't good enough for me. My activity (which extends from `ActionBarActivity`) is dedicated to search, so closing the `SearchView` doesn't make sense. I just want to navigate the user out of there on the first click. (Please no comments about UX or "why" I want to change the default behavior. I have a spec to follow!)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know when the user closed the `SearchView` you can check when the menu item is collapsed:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(menu.findItem(R.id.search_view), new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            //The SearchView is opening
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            //The SearchView is closing. Do stuff here.
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```